# Como obtener el ID de un registro especifico para insertarlo como foreign key en otra tabla. SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Estoy usando las siguientes tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE VENTA(
    ID_VENTA INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    USUARIO_ID_fk INT,
    ID_CLIENTE_fk INT,
    MONTO DECIMAL,
    FECHA DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY(USUARIO_ID_fk) REFERENCES USUARIOS(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_CLIENTE_fk) REFERENCES CLIENTE(ID_CLIENTE)
)

CREATE TABLE DETALLE_VENTAS(
    
    ID_DETALLE INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NO_FACTURA VARCHAR(80) UNIQUE,
    ID_VENTA_fk INT,
    ID_ARTICULO_fk INT,
    CANTIDAD INT,
    MONTO_TOTAL DECIMAL,
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_VENTA_fk) REFERENCES VENTA(ID_VENTA),
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_ARTICULO_fk) REFERENCES ARTICULO(ID)
    
)
```

El problema es el siguiente, el detalle de venta se genera luego de la venta, pero como pueden ver tengo una foreign key en la tabla DETALLE_VENTAS que se llama `ID_VENTA_fk` que se debería insertar el ID de la venta que se ha realizado, pero esto lo hago desde java, no manual obviamente, como obtengo el ID de la venta que acabo de insertar(que es auto-incrementable ese campo) para insertarlo en el campo `ID_VENTA_fk`?.
Se que `LAST_INSERT_ID()` me devuelve el ultimo ID insertado en una tabla pero es esto factible? ya que por ejemplo si hay muchos usuarios insertando registro y se inserta otro registro en ese mismo instante va a obtener el registro equivocado. Hay otra manera de lograr esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Se que LAST_INSERT_ID() me devuelve el ultimo ID insertado en una
> tabla pero es esto factible?

No lo es. En efecto podría devolver un id de otra venta.

Lo que se debe hacer es recuperar el id al mismo tiempo que se hace la inserción, así:

```
statement.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

ResultSet rs= statement.getGeneratedKeys();
if (rs.next()) 
 {
    // aquí está el id generado para esta venta
    System.out.println("Last Inserted ID = "+ rs.getInt(1));
 }
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda! Es exactamente lo que andaba buscando @Lobos